# silverlight how to remove the abstract definition from the UserControl declaration

Tags: .net, silverlight, user-controls

I have SilverLight USercontrol and while  Opening its  design Part ,I am Getting this Error

```
Cannot create an instance of "DialogBase".
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Core.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal, Boolean supportProtected)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.InstanceBuilders.DependencyObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at MS.Internal.Services.DesignModeValueProviderService.DesignModeValueProviderBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Core.ViewNodeManager.Instantiate(ViewNode viewNode)
```

I am getting suggestion that For this, we have to remove the "abstract" definition from the UserControl declaration

my xaml file is

```
<cc:DialogBase x:Class="LMS.Client.View.FindLeadDialog"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
               xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.View;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
               xmlns:interaction="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
               xmlns:commanding="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Commanding;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
               xmlns:control="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Controls;assembly=LMS.Client.Common"
               xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Controls"
               xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:LMS.Client.Model;assembly=LMS.Client.Model"
               KeyDown="DialogBase_KeyDown" FontSize="10"
               Title="Find Leads">

    .........


</cc:DialogBase>
```

cs File is this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace LMS.Client.View
{
    public partial class FindLeadDialog
    {
        public FindLeadDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       .....
    }
}
```

Please Guide me where to remove tha abstract Definition form the User Control

Comment: you should missing reference

Comment: can you please tell me what exact reference I am missing ?

Comment: You need to change the XAML a bit to prefix the UserControl declaration with a namespace:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625358/inheriting-from-a-usercontrol-abstract-subclass